# rotating a view on touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation, uigesturerecognizer

I have to rotate a view circularly on finger touch...I mean like dialing the old phones number...and the touch should be only on corners.....can any one help me...i have tried it a lot...but was not successes

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to define the `UIRotationGestureRecognize` on the view that you want to rotate and than add a selector method and implement it like this.

Add this to you `viewDidLoad` method

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotate = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotation:)];

[myUIViewObject addGestureRecognizer:rotate];

[rotate release];
```

And then implement the method.

```
- (void) rotation:(UIRotationGestureRecognize *) sender
{
    CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(sender.rotation);
    sender.view.transform = myTransform;
}
```

PS. `myUIViewObject` can be any `UIView` Object that you want to rotate.

Edit:

you will find a lot of information on this here:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/49847-how-find-angle-two-points.html

Comment: Thank you....but i have never used gesture before can you help me more on this...?

Comment: Thanks for your answer...i am using imageView for rotation...adding that from interfaceBuilder ..i have made its userintraction and multipletouch both enable...but still it is not rorating....i have used only your code and nothing more....just replaced -myUIViewObject with imageView...

Comment: you need to create an `IBOutlet` for that imageView and connect it in the IB and instead `myUIViewObject` use the name of your `UIImageView` variable

Comment: I have used the same....ok got it working....but can i make it from one single finger touch...?

Comment: ok so you dont want to use 2 fingers to rotate the uiview object. Ok let me get back to you in awhile.

Comment: +1 Thanks...it was really helpful ...(please replace rotation with rotating in you answer) .......thanks.. great help...