# UIView Rotation using CGAffineTransform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

I want to rotate an UIView using CGAffineTransform and I'm able to rotate View using CGAffineTransform.

But I want to rotate UIView smoothly on finger touch based on swipe gestures.

So like right swipe, left swipe I was able to detect swipe but when I swipe from down to right or from down to left, I'm not able to detect swipe gesture of these types...

Comment: I don't know why some one down voted this question.  Please leave a comment after you down vote.

Comment: @Robin: Thanx again.....I remind this.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sanjay these are the only allowable gestures that a iPhone supports

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwipeGestureRecognizer/direction

so I think you are trying to recognize a diagonal swipe gesture and the its not working.

and also there is a minimum numberOfTouchesRequired required for swipe gesture.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer

And if you want to rotate a UIView object than I think you will find the code in this link

[rotating a view on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189626/rotating-a-view-on-touch/5189675#5189675)

Hope this helps.

Comment: don't mention it dude........If any help needed just comment on any of my questions or answers.  I will try my best to help you.......\