# Rotate NSButton clockwise with animation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I'm trying to rotate an NSButton clockwise until a user manually interrupts it. Here's the code I'm using to accomplish this. I know it used to work at some point. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
 
    CABasicAnimation *a = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    a.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    a.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-M_PI*2];
    [self.reloadButton.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
    a.duration = 2.0; // seconds
    a.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
    [self.reloadButton.layer addAnimation:a forKey:nil];
```

Comment: for future readings. This website is the iOS animation go to http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html

Comment: Thanks for the help but the code above is for NSButton not UIButton.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278852/animated-rotation-of-nsview-contents

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me as long as I set `reloadButton.wantsLayer = YES;`

---

From [Enabling Core Animation Support in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html)

In iOS apps, Core Animation is always enabled and every view is backed by a layer. In OS X, apps must explicitly enable Core Animation support by doing the following:

- Link against the QuartzCore framework. (iOS apps must link against
  this framework only if they use Core Animation interfaces
  explicitly.)
- Enable layer support for one or more of your NSView    objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    CABasicAnimation *rotation;
    rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(M_PI)];
    rotation.duration = 0.2; // Speed
    rotation.repeatCount = 1; // Repeat forever. Can be a finite number.
    [yourButton.layer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"Spin"];
    [yourButton.layer setZPosition:100];
    yourButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

You can change/set duration, repeatCount and toValue to your convenient.

Answer (score -2):

**[EDIT1]**

After seeing that this is for an NS versus a UI button, there are a couple of options:

1) Use an NSTimer and the proper rotation routine for you OSX version (see the link below)

http://digerati-illuminatus.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-do-you-rotate-nsbutton-nstextfield.html

2) If you are using OSX 10.5 or above CoreAnimation was supported, and the below should actually be supported for NSButtons.

Wiki Link

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Animation

**[ORIGINAL]**
Try this code instead:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5000000];
CGAffineTransform rr=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(5000000);
reloadButton.transform=CGAffineTransformConcat(reloadButton.transform, rr);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Here is a link to a SO question that shows both methods

[UIView Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349551/uiview-rotation)

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is for actually for a mac osx app i.e. "NSButton" not "UIButton"